# Will Website Security tests (Security Penetration) hurt my WordPress page?

Tags: wordpress, security

I have a WP page.

I did a security checkup through the usual website auditing tools. I'd like to use a tool specialized for Security checks.

Will it hurt my website somehow?
What would you recommend, should I do the basic tests and leave the penetration software for now if I have WP?

Thank you!

Comment: I voted to close because your last statement appears to be a software recommendation.  It is impossible to state for certain that a specialised tool won't hurt your site, but it is somewhat unlikely.

Comment: I see, so website penetration tests will hurt my site?

The last statement was supposed to be general, both if you recommend doing the basic security and leaving the rest out for now or if should I use penetration software. 

But yes, if that would be the second case, I guess wanted some recommendations.

Comment: I think Penetration software can identify some known vulnerabilities and avenues to explore, but a lot of it depends on the skill of the operator.